# yum complains (incorrectly?) of MySql dependencies - when installing zenoss

Tags: mysql, dependencies, rpm, yum, zenoss

I'm trying to install Zenoss Core - following the instructions in the installation manual, but it complains on dependencies which seems it should not. Looks like it is not looking at the locally installed packages.

*Could you suggest a way to change the yum command to get around this problem?*

To illustrate, even though all my installed MySql RPMs **are** of version **5.6.10-1.el6**

```
[root@ip-10-110-175-98 tmp]# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
MySQL-server-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-client-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
```

Still, I get the below errors complaining that they are **not >= 5.5.13**

```
[root@ip-10-110-175-98 tmp]# yum -y --nogpgcheck --enablerepo=epel localinstall zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, rhui-lb, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64.rpm: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
Marking zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zenoss.x86_64 0:4.2.0-1586.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: memcached >= 1.4.4 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-client >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-server >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-shared >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-dig >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-dns >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-http >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-ircd >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-ldap >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-ntp >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-perl >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-ping >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-rpc >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-plugins-tcp >= 1.4.15 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp >= 5.3.2.2-9 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-utils >= 5.3.2.2-9 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liberation-fonts-common for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liberation-mono-fonts for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liberation-sans-fonts for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liberation-serif-fonts for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgcj for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: sysstat for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package liberation-fonts-common.noarch 0:1.05.1.20090721-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package liberation-mono-fonts.noarch 0:1.05.1.20090721-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package liberation-sans-fonts.noarch 0:1.05.1.20090721-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package liberation-serif-fonts.noarch 0:1.05.1.20090721-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package libgcj.x86_64 0:4.4.6-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libart_lgpl >= 2.1.0 for package: libgcj-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.4-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nagios-common >= 3.3.1-1 for package: nagios-plugins-1.4.16-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package nagios-plugins-dig.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-dns.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-http.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-ircd.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-ldap.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-ntp.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-perl.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-ping.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-rpc.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-plugins-tcp.x86_64 0:1.4.16-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.5-41.el6_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.5-41.el6_3.1 for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsensors.so.4()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmptrapd.so.20()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmpmibs.so.20()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmphelpers.so.20()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmpagent.so.20()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.20()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.5-41.el6_3.1.x86_64
---> Package net-snmp-utils.x86_64 1:5.5-41.el6_3.1 will be installed
---> Package sysstat.x86_64 0:9.0.4-20.el6 will be installed
---> Package zenoss.x86_64 0:4.2.0-1586.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-client >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-server >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-shared >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libart_lgpl.x86_64 0:2.3.20-5.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package lm_sensors-libs.x86_64 0:3.1.1-10.el6 will be installed
---> Package nagios-common.x86_64 0:3.4.4-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.5-41.el6_3.1 will be installed
---> Package zenoss.x86_64 0:4.2.0-1586.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-client >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-server >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-shared >= 5.5.13 for package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64 (/zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: mysql-server >= 5.5.13
           Available: mysql-server-5.1.47-4.el6.x86_64 (rhui-us-east-1-rhel-server-releases)
               mysql-server = 5.1.47-4.el6
           Available: mysql-server-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64 (rhui-us-east-1-rhel-server-releases)
               mysql-server = 5.1.52-1.el6_0.1
           Available: mysql-server-5.1.61-1.el6_2.1.x86_64 (rhui-us-east-1-rhel-server-releases)
               mysql-server = 5.1.61-1.el6_2.1
           Available: mysql-server-5.1.61-4.el6.x86_64 (rhui-us-east-1-rhel-server-releases)
               mysql-server = 5.1.61-4.el6
           Available: mysql-server-5.1.66-1.el6_3.x86_64 (rhui-us-east-1-rhel-server-releases)
               mysql-server = 5.1.66-1.el6_3
           Available: mysql-server-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 (rhui-us-east-1-rhel-server-releases)
               mysql-server = 5.1.66-2.el6_3
           Available: mysql-server-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64 (rhui-us-east-1-rhel-server-releases)
               mysql-server = 5.1.67-1.el6_3
Error: Package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64 (/zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: mysql-client >= 5.5.13
Error: Package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64 (/zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: mysql-shared >= 5.5.13
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Machine is a virtual Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3

My /etc/yum.conf is:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3

#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove MySQL 5.6.10 and use an older one- 5.5.28-1 (i tried with 5.5.30). make sure you get client, server, and shared.  I hit my head on a wall all afternoon on this same issue.

Comment: Thanks mmmmmScotch.  
I found that the following RPMs coexist without complaints:
zenoss-4.2.3-1695.el6.x86_64
MySQL-server-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-client-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

The case doesn't match. Seriously. `MySQL` and `mysql` are two totally different packages.

That said, I know nothing about zenoss (I came for the `rpm` tag). Where did you get your `MySQL` package to install? I don't know which is the standard format for it, but they probably should have put a virtual `%provides` tag for `mysql`...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mmmmmScotch.
I found that the following RPMs coexist without complaints:
zenoss-4.2.3-1695.el6.x86_64
MySQL-server-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-client-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.x86_64