# Zenoss core installation compatibility issue with MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, zenoss

I am facing an issue between the Zenoss core installation and MySQL rpms.
The Zenoss core installation won't complete, complaining about mysql-client and mysql-shared versions, even though I have newer versions installed. As suggested in [this Quest/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736942/yum-complains-incorrectly-of-mysql-dependencies-when-installing-zenoss) ,

I also tried to install a 5.5.41 client package but it did not change anything. Here's the situation:

```
[root@bstfe1032 Zenoss]# yum -y --nogpgcheck localinstall zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64.rpm
[...]
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64 (/zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: mysql-client >= 5.5.13
Error: Package: zenoss-4.2.0-1586.el6.x86_64 (/zenoss-4.2.0.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: mysql-shared >= 5.5.13
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

[root@bstfe1032 Zenoss]# rpm -qa|grep -i mysql
MySQL-client-5.6.22-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-5.6.22-1.el6.x86_64
```

The Zenoss core install doc points to MySQL packages from mysql.org and this is where I got them.

Any idea of what I should try next ? I am using CentOS 6, this is a testbed and not a production machine because I wanted to give Zenoss core a test drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing "old" packages (zenoss-4.2.0) with too new one (MySQL 5.6) and it's not probably handled correctly in Zenoss core packages.

The best option for you is to use autodeploy script - https://github.com/zenoss/core-autodeploy/blob/4.2.5/core-autodeploy.sh

It will download last Zenoss packages from http://sourceforge.net/projects/zenoss/files/zenoss-4.2/zenoss-4.2.5/
and MySQL packages from ftp://mirror.anl.gov/pub/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/

See http://wiki.zenoss.org/Install_Zenoss for more information.

Comment: You were right on the zenoss version, my mistake. The autodeploy script did not work at first because 1) MySQL 5.6 leftovers made that MySQL 5.5 could not start, I had to uninstall 5.5, remove /etc/my.cnf and /var/lib/mysql, then 2) could not use epel repo, had to edit epel.repo to replace https by http in order to get metalink and then go on. Finally it is installed.